# FPDF add_font python - Bangla Font file xxx.ttf cannot be embedded due to copyright restrictions

Tags: runtime-error, fpdf, bangla-font

from fpdf import FPDF
pdf.add_font('SolaimanLipi','','filename.ttf', uni=True)

**RuntimeError: ERROR - Font file /content/drive/SolaimanLipi.ttf cannot be embedded due to copyright restrictions.**

I have using python fpdf to write bangla in a pdf. But while i use SolaimanLipi font it shows me this error. How can i solve this?

Comment: The font doesn't allow embedding. Use another one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. I had similar issue while trying to create pdf file containing bengali fonts. I checked several fonts and the ['Bangla.ttf'](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/Bangla.ttf) worked for me. You may try the following code in python:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf=FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('bngla', '', 'Bangla.ttf', uni=True)

pdf.set_font("bngla", size=15)

pdf.cell(200,10,txt=" বাংলার গান ",ln=1,align='C')

pdf.output("out.pdf")
```